# echoing a php file into a modal that is inside a modal | PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I have this php page. I'm struggling to find a solution to this one as whenever I call this page inside a modal, it does not show.

I tried several changes to this one, like changing the quotations of ever single elements inside the code, changing the echoing structure, and modifying to all just for me to be able to echo it, but no luck in all of them.

This serves as my *earnings_amendment_table.php*

```
<?php include 'backend/session.php'; ?>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['referenceno']))
$id=$_POST['referenceno'];
$sql = "select credit, debit, referenceid, datedue,
referenceno, earningsamendment.employeeidno, earningsamendment.accounttitle, earningsamendment.postedby, approvedby,
notedby,employeemasterfile.lastname,employeemasterfile.firstname,employeemasterfile.middlename,
earningsamendment.particulars,earningsamendment.accounttype
from earningsamendment
left join employeemasterfile on earningsamendment.employeeidno= employeemasterfile.employeeidno
where referenceno='$id' order by datedue desc";
    $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array(), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));

    $out = "
    <div class='box-body'>
        <table id='earnings_amendment_view' class='table table-bordered' style='table-layout: fixed; display: table'>
            <thead>
                <th></th>
                  <th>Reference ID.</th>
                  <th>Reference No.</th>
                  <th>Employee Name</th>
                  <th>Account Title</th>
                  <th>Amount</th>
                  <th>Activity</th>
                  <th>Posted By</th>
                  <th>Validated By</th>
                  <th>Noted By</th>
                  <th>Tools</th>
                </thead>
            <tbody>
    ";

    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
                      echo "
                      <tr data-key-1=".$row['particulars']." data-key-2=".$row['accounttype']." data-key-3=".$row['datedue'].">
                        <td class='details-control'></td>
                          <td>".$row['referenceid']."</td>
                          <td>".$row['referenceno']."</td>
                          <td>".$row['lastname']." ".$row['middlename']." ".$row['firstname']."</td>
                          <td>".$row['accounttitle']."</td>
                          <td>".$row['credit']."</td>
                          <td>".(($row['debit']==$row['credit']) ? 'PAID' : 'FOR TAKE UP' )."</td>
                          <td>".$row['postedby']."</td>
                          <td>".$row['approvedby']."</td>
                          <td>".$row['notedby']."</td>
                        </tr>
                      ";
                    }

    $out .= '
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    ';

    echo $out;
?>
```

This script is being called by this modal caller from *earnings_amendment.php*

```
$(function(){
$("body").on('click', '.edit', function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
             url: 'earnings_amendment_table.php',
            data: {referenceno:id}
        }).done(function(d){
            //console.log('d: '+d);
            $('#earnings_amendment_table_').html(d);
            $('#earnings_amendment_table_').show();
        });
    });
});
```

Along with the clicker, still within the same page (*earnings_amendment.php*)

```
    $("body").on('click', '.select', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#select').modal('show');
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    getRow(id);
$(".modal:visible").modal('toggle');
  });
```

This is the table

```
function format ( dataSource ) {
    var html = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;" class="table table-bordered">';
    for (var key in dataSource){
        html += '<tr>'+
                   '<td>' + key             +'</td>'+
                   '<td>' + dataSource[key] +'</td>'+
                '</tr>';
    } return html += '</table>';  }
var earnings_amendment_employee_view_table = $('#earnings_amendment_view').DataTable({});
      $('#earnings_amendment_view').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {      var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
          var row = earnings_amendment_employee_view_table.row(tr);
          if (row.child.isShown()) {
              row.child.hide();
              tr.removeClass('shown');
          } else {
              // Open this row
              row.child(format({
                  'Particulars : ' : tr.data('key-1'),
                  'Account Type : ' : tr.data('key-2'),
                  'Date Due : ' :  tr.data('key-3')
              })).show();
              tr.addClass('shown');
          } });
```

And, this is the modal where it is being called.

This is *earnings_amendment_modal.php*

```
<!-- Edit -->
<div class="modal fade" id="edit">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:95%">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><b>Update Founder Data</b></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form autocomplete='off'  class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="earnings_amendment_edit.php">
                    <input type="hidden" class="decid" name="id">
                    <input type="hidden" name="year" value="<?php echo $year; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="accounttitle" value="<?php echo $accounttitle; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" class="decid" name="id">
                <!-- Table Loader -->
                <div class="form-group" id="earnings_amendment_table_"><div class="col-sm-9" id="earnings_amendment_table_" style="width:100%">
                </div></div>    
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Close</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What seems to be the problem here? As my modal caller is properly set up.

```
<!-- Table Loader -->
                <div class="form-group" id="earnings_amendment_table_"><div class="col-sm-9" id="earnings_amendment_table_" style="width:100%">
                </div></div>
```

It's only displaying this.

[image: pic]

I tried to check it via purposely doing errors in the table and the error properly displays.

I'm assuming that the main cause of this concern is this line.

```
echo "
                      <tr data-key-1=".$row['particulars']." data-key-2=".$row['accounttype']." data-key-3=".$row['datedue'].">
                        <td class='details-control'></td>
                          <td>".$row['referenceid']."</td>
                          <td>".$row['referenceno']."</td>
                          <td>".$row['lastname']." ".$row['middlename']." ".$row['firstname']."</td>
                          <td>".$row['accounttitle']."</td>
                          <td>".$row['credit']."</td>
                          <td>".(($row['debit']==$row['credit']) ? 'PAID' : 'FOR TAKE UP' )."</td>
                          <td>".$row['postedby']."</td>
                          <td>".$row['approvedby']."</td>
                          <td>".$row['notedby']."</td>
                        </tr>
                      ";
```

As I already have a variable holder `$out` that should hold everything together.

Is there a turnaround for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: where are you loading the content into the modal i cannot see that, mostly you call `.load()` with the url of the page inside the `load`, or maybe i overlooked

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I'm using ````$('#earnings_amendment_table_').html(d);
            $('#earnings_amendment_table_').show();```` to call it into the modal.